# JavaFX Keep Drag and Drop Item Always On Top

Tags: drag-and-drop, javafx

I have a Pane object that holds several draggable objects.  These objects are populated within the Pane from left to right and top to bottom and are all draggable.  The problem comes when one of the items placed before others is dragged, it appears underneath those items that were populated after this one.  I've included a small screen shot of this below.  Here I'm attempting to drag "public", but it appears underneath the objects populated after it.

So, my question is, how do I keep the dragged object "always on top" of other draggable objects?

[image: drag and drop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is solved simply by using the ImageView's toFront() method.